# Choosing a New Relic AddOn for Heroku

Tags: heroku, newrelic

I'm currently trying to decide which New Relic Tier to add on to my Heroku application.
I don't seem to understand the difference between the [Stark](https://addons.heroku.com/newrelic#stark) and the [Wayne](https://addons.heroku.com/newrelic#wayne) tiers.

Although both are free addons, the Wayne tier seems to be a much more limited version of the Stark tier, with one main difference. Wayne doesn't cap the "Maximum monthly average dynos" (meaning it could potentially use too many dyno hours and end up costing a fortune), whereas Stark is capped at 1.5 (meaning it won't use more than 1.5 dyno hours a month).

Am I understanding and interpreting the differences correctly?
Are there any other that I may have missed and/or am I misinterpreting the meaning of the "Maximum monthly average dynos" setting?

Comment: Yes you are correct, but I would check with Heroku just in case

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Wayne is more limited than the Stark Plan as well as the Wayne plan retains data for 8 days and Stark offers 90 days for Metric Data. You will need to check with Heroku regarding Dyno usage.

Comment: Did not know about the data retention period. Thanks!